# unable to record the action performed in hybrid application on android device with jmeter

Tags: android, jmeter

I configured everything correctly i.e my device wifi with jmeter proxy. i am using jmeter 2.12 but when I am launching my hybrid application on device , the Test recorder is not recording anything. Please suggest . I tried everything.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I added the threadgroup in the Test plan and http default request with the server name as that of my proxy server which the hybrid application is using to hit . Added Http Test script recorder to workbench and also recording controller . I added the host ip in my android wi-fi . the connection is correct as when I launch the website then it is recording perfectly but when I am launching and performing action on hybrid android app then it is not recording . please suggest what additional is needed.